# How to join multiple object while the material with shader and uv stays the same?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, shaders

I renamed all the uv so when it was merged it will be merged as 1

[image]

but even after uv is renamed etc. the looks still changes when joining.
[image]

images after joining

what causes this and how do I fix this?

here is the file link:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 objects. The one called *car breakdown* has a material that uses the *Generated* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node. The one called *car breakdown.027* has a *Gradient Texture* node, which by default also works as if it used the *Generated* output of a *Texture Coordinate*. *Generated* takes the proportions of your object into account, if you stretch your object on X in *Edit* mode it will also stretch the texture. When you join all these objects, the new object is longer, it explains why your textures are stretched. The solution is to adjust the position of the needles in the *ColorRamp* nodes of your materials.